# jQuery PJAX plugin not working in HTML website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pjax

I am implementing [jQuery PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) on HTML website but it is not working. I noticed that the area outside the container is getting refreshed.

I have 2 pages:
1. a.html
2. b.html

> A.html page code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
            integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pjax/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // pjax
            $(document).pjax('ul a', '#main')
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Page A
    <div id="main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html">b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the text outside the container is 'Page A'

> B.html page code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
            integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="pjax/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // pjax
            $(document).pjax('ul a', '#main')
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Page B
    <div id="main">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a.html">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="b.html">b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the text outside the container is 'Page B'

Now, I opened **a.html** page in browser then cliced on **b.html** link. And I find that the text becomes Page B. It means the page refreshed, and so jQuery pjax did not worked.

See this below video which illustrates this problem:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pjax probably isn't working because your links are within the pjax container div.

So the link is telling pjax to use ajax to load all the entire `b.html` file into `<div id='main'>`.

From the pjax documentation:

> pjax works by fetching HTML from your server via ajax and replacing
>   the content of a container element on your page with the loaded HTML.
>   It then updates the current URL in the browser using pushState.

An example that replaces the `some text` in `#main` with the html in `b.html` and changes the url to b.html.

File a.html

```
 <body>
 Page A
 <div>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="b.html">b</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="main">
   some text
 </div>
 </body>
```

File b.html...

```
// b.html
<p>Replacement text from b.html</p>
```

Comment: No your solution did not worked. I checked it just now. There is some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

U should change into

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).pjax('a[use-pjax]', '#main');
</script>
```

and if u need pjax just add 'use-pjax in the hyperlink:

```
<div id="main">
<ul>
  <li><a use-pjax href="b.html">a</a></li> /* using pjax */
  <li><a href="b.html>b</a></li> /* not using pjax */
</ul>

.... /* content u like to open */

</div>
```

and everything inside "main".Hope this is help, this is work for me